# What does it mean that 'User' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tree, google-cloud-datastore

Following the answer to one of my questions of a tree-walking algorithm

[MLM downline distribution count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107920/mlm-downline-distribution-count)

I want to walk the entire tree of users and print the nodes but I get a strange error message:

`TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable`

This is the code I tried to run to walk the tree:

```
    downlinestack = []
    distributor=self
    downlinestack += User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch(99999999)
    while downlinestack:
        downline = downlinestack.pop()
        logging.info('downline: %s' %str(downline))
        for person in downline:
            downlinestack.append(User.query(User.sponsor == person.key).fetch(99999999))
            logging.info('person: %s' %str(person.key.id()))
```

How should I change the code so that it walks the tree of users connected via the sponsor property?

Thank you

### Update

I found a recursive solution, it looks like this:

```
def downline(self, person, team, teamlist):
    firstline = User.query(User.sponsor == person.key).fetch(99999999)
    if firstline:
        for person in firstline:
            teamlist.append(person)
            newdownline = self.downline(person, team, teamlist)        
            team.append(newdownline)
    return teamlist           

def this_month_non_manager_silver(self):
    silver = 0
    today = date.today()
    timeline = date(today.year, today.month, 1)
    for person in self.downline(self, [], []):
        logging.info('element:%s' % str(person.key.id()) )
        orders = model.Order.all().filter('distributor_id =',
                    person.key.id()).filter('created >',
                    timeline).filter('status =', 'PAID'
                    ).fetch(999999)
        for order in orders:
            for (idx, item) in enumerate(order.items):
                purchase = model.Item.get_by_id(long(item.id()))
                amount = int(order.amounts[idx])
                silver = silver + amount * purchase.silver \
                        / 1000.000            
    return silver
```

Comment: Which exact line throws the TypeError? It'd help narrow it down immensely.

Comment: The line `for person in downline` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just two nested for's?

```
for downline in User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch(99999999):
    logging.info('downline: %s' %str(downline))
    for person in downline:
        downlinestack.append(User.query(User.sponsor == person.key).fetch(99999999))
        logging.info('person: %s' %str(person.key.id()))
```

Comment: I think that will work. I also found a recursive solution that I posted in an update.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
downlinestack += User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch(99999999)
```

expects the RHS to return a list to extend `downlinestack` with.

```
>>> a = ['a']
>>> a += ['b']
>>> a
['a', 'b']
```

Unless User.query().fetch() returns a list, I suspect that what you meant was

```
downlinstack.append(downlinestack += User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch(99999999))
```

My other guess is that whatever you're appending into `downlinestack` isn't iterable, so the following line fails

```
for person in downline:
```

Comment: The line `for person in downline` fails.

Comment: Which out of `+=` and `.append()` do you mean to use?
`[] += [a,b] = [a,b]`, whereas `[].append([a,b]) = [[a,b]]`, looks like you want the second one. Excuse the pseudocode.

Comment: OK...I just want to print something from every node of the tree and I don't know about the details. I think it should be a regular tree algorithm but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: User.query().fetch() does indeed return a list of User objects. The variable you have called 'downline' is a single User object, not a list of them.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I found a recursive solution that I'm using and I've updated the question with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify by going through the code line by line:

```
downlinestack = []
distributor=self
downlinestack += User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch(99999999)
```

First of all, you haven't told us what `User.query` returns. I'm assuming it's a list of user objects. So now `downlinestack` looks like this: `[User1, User2, User3]`

```
while downlinestack:
    downline = downlinestack.pop()
```

Now `downline` contains a single user popped from the end of the stack, `User3`.

```
    logging.info('downline: %s' %str(downline))
    for person in downline:
```

Here's your error: `User3` *is not iterable*. There's no mystery: it's just not that kind of object. It's not a collection of items that can be accessed in turn, iteratively. If you want to iterate over something here, *you have to produce the iterable yourself*.

There are two possible ways to do so. The first is to iterate over the list returned by User.query:

```
distributor=self
downlinestack = User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch(99999999)
while downlinestack:
    top_person = downlinestack.pop()
    logging.info('top_person: %s' %str(top_person))
    for person in User.query(User.sponsor == top_person.key).fetch(99999999):
        downlinestack.append(person)
```

Your other option is to make `downlinestack` into a list of lists:

```
distributor=self
downlinestack = [User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch(99999999)]
while downlinestack:
    downline_top = downlinestack.pop()
    for person in downline_top:
        downlinestack.append(User.query(User.sponsor == person.key).fetch(99999999))
        logging.info('person: %s' %str(person.key.id()))
```

Either of these should work.

I don't have enough context to test the above, but I created my own simplified test scheme just to illustrate the fact that this really does work.

```
>>> query_tree = {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5], 2: [6], 3: [7, 8, 9, 10], 4: [], 
                  5: [11, 12], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [13], 9: [], 10: [], 11: [14], 
                  12: [], 13: [], 14: []}
>>> stack = query_tree[0][:]   #make a copy to avoid changes to `query_tree`
>>> while stack:
...     top_person = stack.pop()
...     print top_person
...     for person in query_tree[top_person]:
...         stack.append(person)
... 
3
10
9
8
13
7
2
6
1
5
12
11
14
4
```

As you can see, this prints out every person's id in the query tree (except for the root id, 0).

Then the other approach:

```
>>> stack = [query_tree[0]]
>>> while stack:
...     top_person_list = stack.pop()
...     for person in top_person_list:
...         print person
...         stack.append(query_tree[person])
... 
1
2
3
7
8
9
10
13
6
4
5
11
12
14
```

Comment: I thought of making a list of lists but that seems a roundabout way to do it when I just want to walk the tree and add something from every node. It should be a common regular algorithm but I still couldn't manage to do it. I'm updating the question with my efforts. If all else fails I will try a recursive algorithm but that will be much more difficult to implement than the iterative solution.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz, There's nothing roundabout about it. See my edited answer. The above two solutions are equivalent, and equally obvious to me.

Comment: @senderie thanks a lot for the elaboration. In the meantime I found a recursive solution with which I've updated the original question and that recursion appears to work for me.